# An equation with negative exponents in quadratic equations test

Tags: quadratics

There is a problem like this :

$x^{-1} = 2x^{(-1/2)} + 3 , x = $?

in my test. I'm working on it for a half of hour but still i can't solve. Please help me. (Excuse my bad grammar)

Comment: Substitute $y=x^{-1/2}$ and solve wrt $y$.

Comment: so $y^2 - 2y + 3 = 0$ am I right ?

Comment: @Oğuzİsmayiluysal Yes. Solve for $y$, then solve for $x$.

Comment: I would have thought $y^2-2y-3=0$

Comment: @Henry yes it should be -3. And $x = 1/9$ i feel dumb

Answer (score 2):

If you define $y=\frac1{\sqrt{x}}$, then you can find $y$ from the equation, since

$$x^{-1} = 2x^{-\frac12} + 3$$

implies
$$y^2 = 2y + 3$$

and you can find the values of $y$ quite quickly.

Every value of $y$ then gives you a *candidate* value for *x* which you must check for correctness by plugging it into the original equation.

Answer (score 0):

since
$$
x^{-1} = 2x^{-\frac12} +3
$$
by squaring:
$$
x^{-2} = 4x^{-1} +12x^{-\frac12} +9 \\
= 4x^{-1} +12\frac{x^{-1}-3}2 +9\\
=10x^{-1} -9
$$
i.e.
$$
x^{-2} -10x^{-1}+9 =0 
$$
or
$$
(x^{-1}-9)(x^{-1}-1) = 0
$$

Comment: $x=1$ is not a solution

Comment: Take care that squaring, cubing, ..., use to  introduce extra roots; here, this is the case of $x=1$.

Comment: @Henry, Claude ah yes, i should have checked. been caught that way before!